# Absolute Sensor Orientation

Tags: matrix, rotational-matrices

I am using data from a [MISB KLV Local Dataset](http://www.gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/standards/ST060107.pdf) and Matrix operations provided in [NASA Worldwind](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Matrix.java). The MISB data provides the platform orientation in Yaw, Pitch, and Roll as well as the Sensor orientation relative to the Platform in Yaw, Pitch, and Roll. I am attempting to calculate the absolute orientation (Yaw, Pitch, Roll) of the sensor, with respect to North, based on the Platform orientation and the Sensor relative orientation.

I am currently calculating the Platform rotation Matrix and the Sensors relative rotation matrix and multiplying the results together. The resulting rotation matrix does not appear to be correct. According to the MISB documentation in section 6.2.4 the Euler Angle Order of Operations is Yaw, Pitch, then Roll. What is the proper way to combine the rotation matrixes to obtain the absolute rotation?

```
  //use transpose for clockwise rotation     
  Matrix mpYaw   = Matrix.fromRotationZ(pYaw).getTranspose();
  Matrix mpPitch = Matrix.fromRotationY(pPitch).getTranspose();
  Matrix mpRoll  = Matrix.fromRotationX(pRoll).getTranspose();      

  Matrix msYaw   = Matrix.fromRotationZ(sYaw).getTranspose();
  Matrix msPitch = Matrix.fromRotationY(sPitch).getTranspose();
  Matrix msRoll  = Matrix.fromRotationX(sRoll).getTranspose();

  Matrix mpRot = mpYaw.multiply(mpPitch).multiply(mpRoll); //platform      
  Matrix msRot = msYaw.multiply(msPitch).multiply(msRoll); //sensor

  Matrix maRot = mpRot.multiply(msRot); //absolute
```

Sample MISB Data:

```
Platform Heading Angle:175.66308079652094
Platform Pitch Angle:3.4296700949125647
Platform Roll Angle:-0.3982665486617634    
Sensor Rel. Az. Angle:326.08593764856596
Sensor Rel. El. Angle:-21.60937493741949
Sensor Rel. Roll Angle:0.0

Sensor Latitude:33.03482410173622
Sensor Longitude:-114.45451377632772
Sensor True Altitude:1022.4368657969026
Frame Center Lat.:33.01531312661958
Frame Center Lon.:-114.4367867216639
Frame Center El.:79.58953231097883
Slant Range:2883.640118614687
```

EDIT 1:

After applying the suggested fix by @anjruu, it looks like the result is close but still slightly off. I calculated the local NED coordinates to the target location by multiplying the forward vector of the rotation matrix by the MISB provided target distance. I then calculated the local NED coordinates (using [ViewUtil](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/view/ViewUtil.java)) of the MISB provided target location with the origin set to the provided platform location and the results are slightly off.

```
  Matrix mpYaw   = Matrix.fromRotationZ(pYaw).getTranspose();
  Matrix mpPitch = Matrix.fromRotationY(pPitch).getTranspose();
  Matrix mpRoll  = Matrix.fromRotationX(pRoll).getTranspose();      

  Matrix msYaw   = Matrix.fromRotationZ(sYaw).getTranspose();
  Matrix msPitch = Matrix.fromRotationY(sPitch).getTranspose();
  Matrix msRoll  = Matrix.fromRotationX(sRoll).getTranspose();

  Matrix mpRot = mpRoll.multiply(mpPitch).multiply(mpYaw); //platform      
  Matrix msRot = msRoll.multiply(msPitch).multiply(msYaw); //sensor

  Matrix maRot = msRot.multiply(mpRot); //absolute

  Globe globe = new Earth();

  Position pPlatform = Position.fromDegrees(33.03482410173622, -114.45451377632772, 1022.4368657969026);
  Position pTarget   = Position.fromDegrees(33.01531312661958, -114.4367867216639, 79.58953231097883);
  double targetRange = 2883.640118614687;

  Vec4 vTarNED = new Vec4(1,0,0).transformBy3(maRot.getTranspose()).multiply3(targetRange);
  //NED = (-2165.935747907422, 1656.9597179630864, 937.3298046411029, 1.0)

  Matrix localENU = ViewUtil.computePositionTransform(globe, pPlatform);
  Vec4 vTarENU = globe.computePointFromPosition(pTarget).transformBy4(localENU);
  //ENU = (1656.3846316600684, -2163.7501770820236, -943.4305881811306, 1.0)
  //NED = (-2163.7501770820236, 1656.3846316600684,  943.4305881811306, 1.0)
```

Comment: Can you include the Matrix class, or at least the specification for `multiply`? I would guess that `Matrix::multiply` is a right-multiplication, and that the camera pose is relative to the platform pose, meaning that it should be `msRot.multiply(mpRot)`, and that you should reverse the multiplication chain for getting `mpRot` and `msRot`, but I can't tell without knowing what `multiply` actually does.

Comment: @anjruu The NASA WorldWind link in the post links to the Matrix class.

Comment: So it does, sorry. Yeah, `A.multiply(B)` is `A*B` (which is sane), so I think that it should be `Matrix mpRot = mpRoll.multiply(mpPitch).multiply(mpYaw);`, similarly for `msRot`, and `maRot`.

Comment: Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix.

Comment: @anjruu I added a test case to verify your changes but I am still getting slightly incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

For the further researchers, I've faced with the same problem. The main problem is the error ratio of sensors, to directly set view position and orientation from sensor data you need to calculate this errors and add them as offset values. But, likely we have World Wind to handle most calculations for us.

With using any 3D Engine you don't actually any given angular information, because you already have both eye and lookAt positions. You can calculate the necessary orientation values from these Positions, also you can manage it manually and automatically.

Here, in my function sets the camera position according to the given MISB KLV Data.

```
public void setCameraPosition(BTelemetryData pData){


    // Get Platform Location Information
    Angle tPlatformLatitude    = Angle.fromDegrees(Double.parseDouble(pData.getAlternatePlatformLatitude()));
    Angle tPlatformLongitude   = Angle.fromDegrees(Double.parseDouble(pData.getAlternatePlatformLongitude()));
    double tPlatformAltitude   = Double.parseDouble(pData.getPlatformGPSAltitude());
    Position tPlatfromPosition = new Position(tPlatformLatitude, tPlatformLongitude ,tPlatformAltitude);

    // Get LookAt Location Information
    Angle tLookAtLatitude = Angle.fromDegrees(Double.parseDouble(pData.getFrameCenterLatitude()));
    Angle tLookAtLongitude= Angle.fromDegrees(Double.parseDouble(pData.getFrameCenterLongitude()));
    // Note must take into account the surface elevation at given lat lon.
    double tLookAtAltitude= getWwd().getModel().getGlobe().getElevation(tLookAtLatitude, tLookAtLongitude);
    Position tLookAtPosition = new Position(tLookAtLatitude, tLookAtLongitude ,tLookAtAltitude);

    // First things first, we need to Set Field of View
    getView().setFieldOfView(Angle.fromDegrees(Double.parseDouble(pData.getSensorHorizontalFieldofView())));
    if (useAutoCameraPosition())
        setCameraPositionAutomatically(tLookAtPosition, tPlatfromPosition);
    else
        calculateAndSetCameraPosition(tLookAtPosition, tPlatfromPosition);

    getView().firePropertyChange(AVKey.VIEW, null, getView());

}

public void setCameraPositionAutomatically(Position pLookAtPosition, Position pEyePosition){
    getView().setEyePosition(pEyePosition);
    getView().setOrientation(pEyePosition, pLookAtPosition);
}
public void calculateAndSetCameraPosition(Position pLookAtPosition, Position pEyePosition){
        double tPitch   = getPitchAngleBetweenPositionInDegrees(pLookAtPosition, pEyePosition);
        double tHeading = getHeadingAngleBetweenPositionInDegrees(pLookAtPosition, pEyePosition);

        getView().setEyePosition(pEyePosition);
        getView().setHeading(Angle.fromDegrees(tHeading));
        getView().setPitch(Angle.fromDegrees(tPitch));
}


public double getPitchAngleBetweenPositionInDegrees(Position pLookAt, Position pEyePosition) {

    // Calculate the radius at given look at position
    double tRadius = getWwd().getModel().getGlobe().getRadiusAt(pLookAt);

    // Find the Surrounding Radial Length Between those positions
    double tRadialDistance = Position.greatCircleDistance(pLookAt, pEyePosition).getRadians() * tRadius;

    // Find the Ratio Between Distance, which will give the offset and Angle
    double tTheta = tRadialDistance / tRadius;

    // Get the surface elevation of lookatposition
    double tLookAtElevation = pLookAt.getElevation();

    // Get Altitude of given eye position
    double tEyeAltitude = pEyePosition.getAltitude();

    // Delta Location Changes in cartesian
    double tDeltaX  = (tRadius + tLookAtElevation) * Math.cos(tTheta);
    double tDeltaY  = (tRadius + tLookAtElevation) * Math.sin(tTheta);
    double tDeltaZ  =  tRadius + tEyeAltitude - tDeltaX;

    double alpha = Math.atan(tDeltaZ / tDeltaY)  - tTheta;

    // Convert NED to World Wind Coordinate System. The Pitch angle should be 90 - calculated.
    double degrees = 90 - Math.toDegrees(alpha); 

    System.out.println("Elevation Angle Between Positions = " + degrees);
    return degrees;
}

public  double getHeadingAngleBetweenPositionInDegrees(Position pLookAtPosition, Position  pEyePosition) {

    double tLatEye     = pEyePosition.getLatitude().radians;
    double tLatLookAt  = pLookAtPosition.getLatitude().radians;

    double tLonLookAt = pLookAtPosition.getLongitude().radians;
    double tLonEye    = pEyePosition.getLongitude().radians;
    double dLon = (tLonLookAt - tLonEye);

    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(tLatLookAt);
    double x = Math.cos(tLatEye) * Math.sin(tLatLookAt) - Math.sin(tLatEye)
             * Math.cos(tLatLookAt) * Math.cos(dLon);

    // Calculate the Bearing Angle. 
    double tBearing = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));

    // Calculate the absolute value of that Angle
    tBearing = (tBearing + 360) % 360;

    // Note that world wind takes the Heading in clockwise, if you want to make it counter clockwise, you need to subtract it from 360 degrees
   //tBearing = 360 - tBearing;

    return tBearing;
}
```

!
//

In my code I didnt set the roll angle, but according to the document, you can simply sum both sensor and platfrom roll angles, then set the roll angle.

One little note, World Wind has two different view classes BasicOrbitView and BasicFlyView, to simulate the given data you must use the BasicFlyView.  The reason of that in FlyView you keep your camera positions when you set angles but on the other hand, in OrbitView you keep your lookAt position  and change both angles and camera position relative to these angles. You can use setOrientation method if the precision is good enough for you.

[The result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyLff.png)

Good coding :)